# Can value in PropertyValue be an array?

Tags: schema.org

I need to include a property for a schema for retailers that can hold multiple text values. `PropertyValue` seems to be the best bet, but can the value be an array? For example, if I want to list the emails that the store uses, can I have something like below?

```
{
  "@type": "PropertyValue",
  "name": "emails",
  "value": ["abc@store.com","xyz@store.com"]
}
```